# Parsing specific JSON-like data (NextSTEP PList) from Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, property-list

i'm writing a client to a third-party API, and they provide data in a weird format. At first, it might look like JSON but it's not, and i'm a bit confused about how i should handle that.

It's a key-value based format (much like JSON).

- Keys are separated by '=' from their values.
- Keys and values are wrapped within double-quotes.
- Dictionaries start with '{' and end with '}'.
- Arrays start with '('
  and end with ')'
- Lines end with ';' (Excepted for arrays content) and end-of-line character (\r i think).
- Sometimes, there seem to be unicode (Stuff like \U2623 for the BioHazard sign) in strings.

What could possibly be this format? Shall i use a premade gem to parse it, or should i build my own parser?

```
{ "anArray" = (
  "100",
  "200",
  "300"
  );
  "aDictionary" = {
    "aString" = "Something";
  };
}
```

**EDIT** This format seems to be Apple's property list, but it's not XML neither Binary... This make sense as the API is from a WebObjects webservice. i will try to use CFPropertyList gem to parse it, if there is a better solution, please let me know.

**EDIT 2** This is a [NextSTEP Property List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list).

Comment: Could you provide a more robust example of the format? Is it legal to omit the trailing `;` after a dictionary value? What happens when you have a key or value with a double-quote in it? Can you nest dictionaries in arrays, arrays in dictionaries? Are there always single spaces surrounding the ` = ` delimiters?

Comment: +1 for a fun question. For future visitors, it would be really helpful if you could put a real name to this format. It's certainly not an Apple PList.

Comment: @Phrogz: After some research, it appears to be NeXTSTEP's PList format. It's recognized by Apple as a valid PList format, but gems such as CFPropertyList don't know about it.

Comment: @Phrogz: Yes, you can nest dictionaries. Yes, you can nest arrays. i don't know about omitting the ';'. The equal sign is always surrounded by spaces in the API exposure, but i don't know about the exact specifications. i can't provide an example content right now, because the API is under NDA itself, only the format seems to be known widely, that's why i don't think talking about it breaks the NDA.

Comment: The `;` are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a robust answer using a custom [StringScanner](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html)-based parser. It allows whitespace to be optional, allows trailing commas after the last item in a list and allows omitting the semicolon after the last dictionary key/value pair. It allows the outermost item to be an dictionary, array, or string. And it allows really any sort of legal string content, including parens and curly braces and escaped text like `\n`.

Seen in action:

```
p parse('{ "array" = ( "1", "2", ( "3", "4" ) ); "hash"={ "key"={ "more"="oh}]yes;!"; }; }; }')
#=> {"array"=>["1", "2", ["3", "4"]], "hash"=>{"key"=>{"more"=>"oh}]yes;!"}}}

puts parse('("Escaped \"Quotes\" Allowed", "And Unicode \u2623 OK")')
#=> Escaped "Quotes" Allowed
#=> And Unicode ☣ OK
```

The code:

```
require 'strscan'
def parse(str)
  ss, getstr, getary, getdct = StringScanner.new(str)
  getvalue = ->{
    if    ss.scan /\s*\{\s*/   then getdct[]
    elsif ss.scan /\s*\(\s*/   then getary[]
    elsif str = getstr[]       then str
    elsif ss.scan /\s*[)}]\s*/ then nil end
  }
  getstr = ->{
    if str=ss.scan(/\s*"(?:[^"\\]|\\u\d+|\\.)*"\s*/i)
      eval str.gsub(/([^\\](?:\\\\)*)#(?=[{@$])/,'\1\#')
    end
  }
  getary = ->{
    [].tap do |a|
      while v=getvalue[]
        a << v
        ss.scan /\s*,\s*/
      end
    end
  }
  getdct = ->{
    {}.tap do |h|
      while key = getstr[]
        ss.scan /\s*=\s*/
        if value=getvalue[] then h[key]=value; ss.scan(/\s*;\s*/) end
        end
      end
    end
  }
  getvalue[]
end
```

As an alternative to rolling your own parser from scratch in the future, you might also want to look into the [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org) Ruby library.

---

**Edit**: I've replaced the implementation of `getstr` above with one that should prevent running arbitrary Ruby code inside the `eval`. For more details, see *["Eval a string without interpolation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695890/eval-a-string-without-string-interpolation/16695891#16695891)*. Seen in action:

```
@secret = "OH NO!"
$secret = "OH NO!"
@@secret = "OH NO!"
puts parse('"\"#{:NOT&&:very}\" bad. \u262E\n#@secret \\#$secret \\\\#@@secret"')
```

Comment: Impressive work in such short delay. i really appreciate your answer. However, an answer without eval'ing would suit more. i'm not familiar with TreeTop and i don't want to spend too much time immersing myself into it for now, so unless you provide another answer without eval calls, i will select this one as the right one but will stick to my system('/usr/bin/plutil') for now, until we need to make the project more portable. Thanks a lot Phrogz very good work!

Comment: I've edited the answer to avoid the danger of `eval` on the string, and removed the comment that warned of its danger.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks! i will test this piece of code and give you some feedback. Would you mind adding a few comments to the code?

Comment: Ah... The parser doesn't work. Without debugging it, it would be hard for me to pinpoint the exact "why". Maybe i can provide you with some example content to your email address?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the notation. As a non-native english spearker, i'm wondering... Should i translate the first character as a literal "exclamationmark", or an "i", or a "bang"? :)

Comment: @Pierre Exclamation point before the at. Or, alternatively, my first name before the at.

Comment: You can use Parslet to do an EBNF/Antlr style parser definition, to generate a recursive descent parser.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very quick-and-dirty hack that transforms the syntax into valid Ruby and then evals it. Note that this *could* be dangerous. More importantly, this will convert all parentheses inside keys and values into square brackets.

```
def parse(str)
  eval(
    str
      .gsub( /" = (?=[({"])/, '" => ' )      # Dictionary separators become =>
      .gsub( /(?<=[)}"]); (?=[)}"])/, ', ' ) # Dictionary semicolons become ,
      .tr( '()', '[]' )                      # ALL parens become square brackets
  )
end

p parse('{ "anArray" = ( "100", "200", "300" ); "aDictionary" = { "aString" = "Something"; }; }')
#=> {"anArray"=>["100", "200", "300"], "aDictionary"=>{"aString"=>"Something"}}
```