# Eval a string without string interpolation

Tags: ruby, regex, eval

*AKA How do I find an unescaped character sequence with regex?*

Given an environment set up with:

```
@secret = "OH NO!"
$secret = "OH NO!"
@@secret = "OH NO!"
```

and given string read in from a file that looks like this:

```
some_str = '"\"#{:NOT&&:very}\" bad. \u262E\n#@secret \\#$secret \\\\#@@secret"'
```

I want to evaluate this as a Ruby string, but without interpolation. Thus, the result should be:

```
puts safe_eval(some_str)
#=> "#{:NOT&&:very}" bad. ☮
#=> #@secret #$secret \#@@secret
```

By contrast, the `eval`-only solution produces

```
puts eval(some_str)
#=> "very" bad. ☮
#=> OH NO! #$secret \OH NO!
```

---

At first I tried:

```
def safe_eval(str)
  eval str.gsub(/#(?=[{@$])/,'\\#')
end
```

but this fails in the malicious middle case above, producing:

```
#=> "#{:NOT&&:very}" bad. ☮
#=> #@secret \OH NO! \#@@secret
```

Comment: The motivation for this question is a simple way to safely implement the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682090/parsing-specific-json-like-data-nextstep-plist-from-ruby/16682890#16682890).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via regex by ensuring that there are an even number of backslashes before the character you want to escape:

```
def safe_eval(str)
  eval str.gsub( /([^\\](?:\\\\)*)#(?=[{@$])/, '\1\#' )
end
```

…which says:

- Find a character that is not a backslash `[^\\]`
- followed by two backslashes `(?:\\\\)`

  - repeated zero or more times `*`
- followed by a literal `#` character
- and ensure that after that you can see either a `{`, `@`, or `$` character.
- and replace that with

  - the non-backslash-maybe-followed-by-even-number-of-backslashes
  - and then a backslash and then a `#`

Comment: But am I missing an attack vector for running arbitrary Ruby code?

Comment: @Phogrez: If you're running this on a server anywhere, say goodbye to your data. If this is just a local app, this is good enough.

Comment: @Linuxios ["Maybe before we rush to adopt eval we should stop to consider the consequences of blithely giving this technology such a central position in our server"](http://xkcd.com/1215/)? Which is to say, _"It sounds like you're giving good advice, but all you seem to actually be doing is fearmongering based on the presence of `eval`. Could you please provide a concrete attack vector that this does not guard against?"_

Comment: @Phogrez: Agree with the XKCD, Let me think on this for a moment.

Comment: What's preventing someone from just puttong some Ruby code instead of a string? E.g.: `some_str = 'system('rm -rf /')`?

Comment: @Linuxios This string is being extracted by [a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682090/parsing-specific-json-like-data-nextstep-plist-from-ruby/16682890#16682890) and is thus guaranteed to be surrounded by double quotes. The parser also ensures that it can't be something like `"foo" + evil_code + "bar"`.

Comment: Alright. Here's something: What if the string equals (without your parsers quotes around it: `str";puts 'Doing something bad';"return value of safe_eval`? I run this, and the message prints.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30427/discussion-between-linuxios-and-phrogz)

Comment: @Linuxios The parser extracts from a `"` up to the next `"` that is not escaped. It's guaranteed to be a single string.

Answer (score 1):

How about not using eval at all? As per [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9562292#9562292) comment in chat, all that's necessary are escaping quotes, newlines, and unicode characters. Here's my solution:

```
ESCAPE_TABLE = {
  /\\n/ => "\n",
  /\\"/ => "\"",
}
def expand_escapes(str)
  str = str.dup
  ESCAPE_TABLE.each {|k, v| str.gsub!(k, v)}
  #Deal with Unicode
  str.gsub!(/\\u([0-9A-Z]{4})/) {|m| [m[2..5].hex].pack("U") }
  str
end
```

When called on your string the result is (in your variable environment):

```
"\"\"\#{:NOT&&:very}\" bad. ☮\n\#@secret \\\#$secret \\\\\#@@secret\""
```

Although I would have preferred not to have to treat unicode specially, it is the only way to do it without `eval`.

Comment: FWIW, the chat comment was meant as an example, not a full list. [All escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Backslash_Notation) need to be supported, e.g. `\t` and `\r` and `\s` and such. But that's obviously extensible in your solution.

Comment: Instead of _n_ gsubs, one per replacement, though, I would suggest a single gsub with the block form that uses the lookup table to determine the replacement string.

Comment: @Phrogz: That's a good idea. I'll do it later, I'm a little busy right now.